# Solve for two variable in terms of other

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

How do I solve for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in terms of $\theta$ using the equations
$$a^2 \cos^2\theta \:+\:b^2 \sin^2\theta \:=\:a^2\cos^2\alpha $$
and
$$b^2 \cos^2\theta \:+\:a^2 \sin^2\theta \:=\:a^2\cos^2\alpha\ + a^2\sin^2\beta \sin^2\alpha$$

Comment: You can lose those square roots, for starters. $\sqrt p = \sqrt q \Rightarrow p=q$

Comment: Do you just want to solve for $\alpha$? For example, do you just want to have an equation $$\alpha=...$$

Comment: For both $\alpha$ in terms of $\theta$ and $\beta$ in terms of $\theta$

Comment: Give it a try!  The first equation allows you to get $\cos^2 \alpha$ in terms of $a,b,\theta$.  You can then eliminate $\alpha$ in the second equation.  If you try this and run into an actual difficulty, sharing that difficulty may help Readers understand what you are getting stuck on (rather than feeling you are trying to stick them with routine algebra).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** From the first equation you can immediately obtain $\alpha$. Then, in the second equation, plug in the first one and use that $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$.